# jQuery scrolling out of view issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am working on building a schedule. So far it's pretty straight-forward. There is one bit of functionality I am having issues with.

I have an `ul` that has a fixed height to allow scrolling. There are "Labels" (`li.dayLabel`) withing the `ul` that separate the hours. What I am trying to do is to have it so that when a label is scrolled out of view it will change the text in the placeholder to it's text. Then once that works, I need it to work in reverse. So when they label scrolls back into view it updates the placeholder. Basically, I am trying to make the placeholder be a title for the available items until another label is then scrolled out of view. This is for scrolling from the top. So as you scroll down the list the placeholder is meant to be a title for the section you are viewing until you reach another section and it takes its place. Then when you scroll back down I need it to replace the text with the previous `li.dayLabel` so the sections stay organized. I hope this makes sense.

You can see what I am trying to do by looking at the [original](http://sonlifetv.com/tvprogramguide.html) that I am basing this off of. Notice how the placeholder changes as you scroll down the list and changes back when you scroll back up.

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B6QP)  // Note: line 54 is the part that is in question

I originally used:

```
$(".snlf-schedule-list li.dayLabel:visible:first").text();
```

as the [`:first` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) is suppose to only match a single element.

I later tried:

```
$(".snlf-schedule-list li.dayLabel:visible").filter(":eq(0)")
```

as this is suppose to be the same thing.

It seems that when an element is out of view it still is considered `:visible` I believe this is my issue.

Am I doing this completely wrong? I was under the impression that when you scroll an element like this it should no longer be `:visible`. After reading the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) I have learned that this is not the correct selector to use.

It would appear that [scrollTop](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) is how I should be doing this. Now I have used `scrollTop` for scrolling down pages to disable animations when not in view but I am not clear on how to untilize this for a `ul` with scrollbars.

I tried:

```
var _first = $('li.dayLabel:first'); // next element to scroll out of view?
if( $(this).scrollTop() > (_first.offset().top+_first.height())) {
    // Out of view
    console.log("out");
} else {
    // in view
    console.log("in");
}
```

Updated Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8B6QP/1/)

But it seems to be redundant as it's already calculating the first element so I am not sure how to get the correct element (the next one that's about to scroll out of view.) Then I need this to work when they scroll back up...

Any insight on this is much appreciated. Hopefully it's something simple I am just over complicating or missing completely.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my case was:

```
// Set placeholder text on scroll
var _scrollCagePositionTop = $(".snlf-schedule-list").offset().top;
var _first = $('li.dayLabel:first'); // first dayLabel element
$(".snlf-schedule-list").scroll(function(){
    var _lastOffText = $(_first).text();
    $("li.dayLabel").each(function() {
        if ($(this).offset().top < _scrollCagePositionTop) {
            _lastOffText = $(this).text();
        }
    });
    $("#schedule-placeholder").text(_lastOffText);
});
```

What I did was set the known position of the top of the scroll cage (`_scrollCagePositionTop`)

When the user scrolls I set a variable `_lastOffText` that keeps track of the last item text content when scrolled out of view (less offset top than the palceholder). I then set this value to the placeholder.

This method allows me to have the proper text in my placeholder when the user scrolls up or down.

To fix the issue of an empty placeholder when the user scrolls back to the top I just set the default of `_lastOffText` to be the text of the first label (`$(_first).text()`)

Hope others find this useful.

Here is the working demo: [jsFiddle Final](http://jsfiddle.net/8B6QP/4/)